# Activity Orientation Change

Tags: android, class, orientation

Can I tell a different activity to change its orientation from the current activity using this method?

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
game.class.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

but this will not compile.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What are you trying to achieve?  The activity is not visible anyway so what's the point of trying to rotate it?

Comment: I want to add an option to run the next activity in portrait or landscape mode on a button click from the current activity.

Comment: in your `onCreate` of the activity you want to change is the only time you can do this

Comment: in that case, pass some flag to next activity and depending on it, switch to desired orientation.

Comment: OK, but when I put that method in the onCreate method of my activity, the application restarts.  Is there any way to use the method before the activity is fully created?

Comment: In onCreate method of other activity this this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); should work. What did you mean under "application restarts" ?

Comment: @Divers pretty sure he means that the activity gets re-created because of the orientation change like it would if you manually change rotated the device yourself. In either case `onCreate` is the first method that gets called in the activity so there is nothing before that where you can place this. You might want to rethink this idea

Comment: @tyczj Yes that is correct.  The activity is re-created because the orientation change takes place in the onCreate method.  Any ideas on another way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Shane no there is not, you need rethink this approach as you cannot do what you want without that effect

Answer (score 1):

Edit.
Just transfer the string for example orientation with the selected value. And build it using constructor in the another class. Then in the onCreate you can write if(this.orientation == "Landscape){
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

Hope it helps you.

Comment: he wants to give the user a choice so doing this would not work in this case

Comment: Oh, yeah.. kind of awkard :D Well, sorry.

Comment: You can request that your post is deleted if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the next activity, send extra information on the intent that you use to start the next activity with and in next Activity's onCreate change the orientation according to the information passed.

Example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Orientation", "landscape");
startActivity(intent)
```

In the next Activity do the following

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String orientation = intent.getStringExtra("Orientation")

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" do this in manifest
```

Use onConfigurationChanged method of activity to detect Orientation Change

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

}
```

}

Comment: The orientation cannot be changed in the onCreate method because the activity is then re-created

Comment: In the manifest you can say that you will handle orientation change.

Comment: That's not what I meant. What I mean is that you can say when orientation change happens I will handle it.

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"